# class parameter of generic type

Tags: java, generics, parameter-passing, suppress-warnings, raw-types

This code does not compile:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  someMethod(SomeInterfaceImpl.class); // Compile error
}

static <T> void someMethod(Class<? extends SomeInterface<T>> param) {}

interface SomeInterface<T> {}

class SomeInterfaceImpl<T> implements SomeInterface<T> {}
```

This error is shown:
`The method someMethod(Class<? extends SomeInterface<T>>) in the type SomeApp is not applicable for the arguments (Class<SomeInterfaceImpl>)`

I could ignore generics and annotate with `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`.

How can I change my code to be able to use this method without omitting the generics definition? Either I need to change how the method is called and provide some kind of genericified class or I need to change the method definition.

Comment: Note: `?` stands for `Object` class so based on provided information nothing can be said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution

old:

```
static <T> void someMethod(Class<? extends SomeInterface<T>> param) {..}
```

new:

```
static <T extends SomeInterface<?>> void someMethod(Class<T> param) {..}
```

Comment: I made this answer community wiki to encourage others to add proper explanation of why solution from this answer works but OP version doesn't (currently I can't).